# Pairs of numbers with a given LCM

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How can we show that the number of pairs $(a,b)$ (where the pairs $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ are considered same) with $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b) = n$ is equal to

$$\displaystyle\frac{(2e_1+1)(2e_2+1)...(2e_k+1)+1}{2},$$

Where

$n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\dots p_k^{e_k}$, $p_i$s are prime for all  $1\leq i\leq k$.

I managed to guess this formula for a programming problem I was working on, but I'd be interested in a deduction or proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First count the pairs with $\gcd(a,b)=n$ counting $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ as
distinct. You have $a=\prod p_i^{r_i}$ and $b=\prod p_i^{s_i}$
and need $\max(r_i,s_i)=e_i$ for all $i$. So, given a positive integer $e$,
how many pairs $(r,s)$ of nonnegative integers are there with $\max(r,s)=e$?

Comment: +1, I see it now. Assuming $r=e$, then there are $e+1$ such pairs, so $2e+1$ if we consider $(s,r)$ distinct. Does this mean the formula can be simplified to avoid a division by $2$ at the end? Is there a way to count it directly for unordered pairs?

Comment: It's best to compute the number of ordered pairs and then at the last stage adjust to count ordered pairs. They come in twos except for those with $a=b$.