# Finding numbers from given LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If a number N is given to us. Is there any way to find all the combinations of numbers whose LCM is N?

Comment: "all the combinations of numbers"  combinations of two numbers?  three?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the prime factorization of $N$ is $p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$.  Then for each subset $S$ of $\{ \, 1, \ldots, r \, \}$, write down all pairs of numbers $a$ and $b$ computed as follows:

a = $p_1^{f_1} p_2^{f_2} \cdots p_r^{f_r}$

where $f_i = e_i$ for $i \in S$, and $f_j$ is allowed to be any number between $0$ and $e_j-1$ for $j \not\in S$, and

b = $p_1^{g_1} p_2^{g_2} \cdots p_r^{g_r}$

where $g_i = e_i$ for $i \not\in S$, and $f_j$ is allowed to be any number between $0$ and $e_j$ for $j \in S$.

Edit: The above argument assumes you care about the order in which you write the factors.  If you want to enumerate all ordered lists of numbers (not just pairs) with LCM $N$, you can modify the above argument as follows: once you've chosen $S$ and constructed $a$, choose $b$ to be any integer $p_1^{g_1} p_2^{g_2} \cdots p_r^{g_r}$ with $g_i \leq e_i$ for all $i$.  Then construct $c$ in the same manner.  Continued until you have constructed a list of numbers which is one fewer in number than the total you want.  Then construct the final number by the same rule as $b$, $c$, etc., except restrict it to be divisible by $p_i^{e_i}$ for any $i \not\in S$ which for which $p_i^{e_i}$ was not the exact power of $p_i$ dividing any of $b$, $c$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Don't see why it should only be pairs of numbers. Could extend the same argument to cover $3,4...$ numbers with same LCM.

Comment: Good point. It's also not clear if OP wants sets or ordered lists of such numbers, but unless he says otherwise, I'll stop with ordered lists.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the time you asked this question I think you are trying to solve April Long Challenge on CodeChef correct me I am wrong.
You basically need to find all the factors of the given numbers.