# Counting pairs given a condition

Tags: combinatorics, gcd-and-lcm

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/pairs-of-numbers-with-a-given-lcm?noredirect=1&lq=1), what I can understand so far is that the number of pairs with equal lcm $d$ is

$$\prod_i(2e_i+1)$$

where $d=\prod_i p_i^{e_i}$; $p_i$ a prime number. If I ignore the order of the elements in each pair, the number becomes
$$\frac{1+\prod_i(2e_i+1)}{2}. \quad (1)$$

I see that the product is odd, and dividing by 2 would give a noninteger number.

**Question** Why the product is summed by one in the numerator of (1)? Why not $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of pairs $(a,b)$ counted by $\prod$:

- $a<b$
- $a>b$
- $a=b$

If you consider the first two types to be the same, the count is
$$\frac{\prod-1}{2} + 1 = \frac{1+\prod}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, there is only one pair $(a,a): lcm(a,a)=d$.